# Upsert data in postgresql using spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to run a structured streaming application using (py)spark. My data is read from a Kafka topic and then I am running windowed aggregation on event time.

```
# I have been able to create data frame pn_data_df after reading data from Kafka

Schema of pn_data_df
  |
   - id StringType
   - source StringType
   - source_id StringType
   - delivered_time TimeStamp

windowed_report_df = pn_data_df.filter(pn_data_df.source == 'campaign') \
    .withWatermark("delivered_time", "24 hours") \
    .groupBy('source_id', window('delivered_time', '15 minute')) \
    .count()
windowed_report_df = windowed_report_df \
    .withColumn('start_ts', unix_timestamp(windowed_report_df.window.start)) \
    .withColumn('end_ts', unix_timestamp(windowed_report_df.window.end)) \
    .selectExpr('CAST(source_id as LONG)', 'start_ts', 'end_ts', 'count')
```

I am writing this windowed aggregation to my postgresql database which I have already created.

```
CREATE TABLE pn_delivery_report(
   source_id bigint not null,
   start_ts bigint not null,
   end_ts bigint not null,
   count integer not null,
   unique(source_id, start_ts)
);
```

Writing to postgresql using spark jdbc allows me to either `Append` or `Overwrite`. Append mode fails if there is an existing composite key existing in the database, and Overwrite just overwrites entire table with current batch output.

```
def write_pn_report_to_postgres(df, epoch_id):
    df.write \
    .mode('append') \
    .format('jdbc') \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://db_endpoint/db") \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
    .option("dbtable", "pn_delivery_report") \
    .option("user", "postgres") \
    .option("password", "PASSWORD") \
    .save()

windowed_report_df.writeStream \
   .foreachBatch(write_pn_report_to_postgres) \
   .option("checkpointLocation", '/home/hadoop/campaign_report_df_windowed_checkpoint') \
   .outputMode('update') \
   .start()
```

How can I execute a query like

```
INSERT INTO pn_delivery_report (source_id, start_ts, end_ts, COUNT)
VALUES (1001, 125000000001, 125000050000, 128),
       (1002, 125000000001, 125000050000, 127) ON conflict (source_id, start_ts) DO
UPDATE
SET COUNT = excluded.count;
```

in `foreachBatch`.

Spark has a jira feature ticket open for it, but it seems that it has not been prioritised till now.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19335

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue? I am wondering around how to do the same thing.@Abhishek

Comment: @Mahnaz - No. I gave up on this and used ksql instead. You can read up on my implementation on the blog I authored for Confluent. - https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-pushowl-uses-ksqldb-to-scale-analytics-and-reporting-use-cases/

Comment: Thanks, I read your blog, it was a good solution, though it seems expensive. Maintaining and monitoring all of them (spark structured streaming + at least 3 Kafka topic + Ksql + Kafka connect job) should be hard (I mean how you make sure all of them are up and running?). Do you know any orchestration tool for streaming jobs like this? Did you use one? @Abhishek

Comment: @Mahnaz - I did not use Spark Structured Streaming. I used Python workers to stream events to Kafka and used Ksql to aggregate events. Our use case was very simple and we did not use any Orchestration tool. We use Kubernetes for hosting our infra, so maintaining and monitoring becomes very easy. But, you can always go with managed Ksql and Connect on Confluent cloud, which doesn't need any maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

that's worked for me:

```
def _write_streaming(self,
    df,
    epoch_id
) -> None:         

    df.write \
        .mode('append') \
        .format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", f"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres") \
        .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
        .option("dbtable", 'table_test') \
        .option("user", 'user') \
        .option("password", 'password') \
        .save()

df_stream.writeStream \
    .foreachBatch(_write_streaming) \
    .start() \
    .awaitTermination()
```

You need to add ".awaitTermination()" at the end.